Can't connect Android phone to Ubuntu 24.04
I went from Windows 11 to Ubuntu 24.04.1 a few months back. I'm having problems trying to connect my Android phone to my Fujitsu Lifebook A512 laptop that's running Ubuntu using a USB cable, but it's not having any of it. I tried KDE Connect, but it didn't help.

Please [edit] your question, state the Ubuntu version number and describe in detail what exactly you are doing and what you are checking.
When I connect my mobile phone by USB, I have to do something on the phone to switch it from USB charging to a data transfer mode. (Depending on the brand and version this can be done from a popup or it might appear in the notifications.) Then the phone appears in the file manager.
